# Получить данные из ссылки на карту с конструктора карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Дано: ссылка на карту, сделанную на конструкторе карт Яндекса. На карте расчерчены полигонами области.
Цель: получить, имея только ссылку на эту карту, данные полигонов.
С чем работаем: SPA на Vue.js (v2).

Что пробовал: искал, как привязать существующую карту к api я.карт - не нашел. Искал, как по данным из ссылки или из DOM найти глобальный объект карты в консоли - не нашел. Искал по загружаемым JS яндекса какие-то зацепки - не смог найти ничего путного, запутался в коде, не увидел ничего подходящего.

Вопрос: это вообще возможно? Да, видел у некоторых сервисов как, получая ссылку на карту, выводили список "областей" с этой карты. Но как??

**UPDATE**
Получилось, наконец, уточнить через поддержку Яндекса, это на самом деле недоступный функционал оказался, нет там такой возможности. А то, что я видел в другом сервисе - устаревшая и неактуальная информация. сейчас там такого не предлагают. За сим, полагаю, вопрос закрыт...